# TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list' Please

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi im making a code for recalculating serving sizes in a recipe book but i keep getting this

> error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

This is my Code:

```
testfile = open(fname, 'r+')
new_ingrediants = input("How Many People Do You Want To Recalculate For?")
new_ingrediants = int(new_ingrediants)
ingrediant1 = open(fname).readlines(3)
ingrediant1 = int(ingrediant1)
new_ingrediant1 = (ingrediant1*new_ingrediants)
print (new_ingrediant1)
```

Comment: This `.readlines(3)` returns a list, you cannot pass a list to `int()`

Answer (score 1):

`readlines(3)` reads 3 lines from the file and returns a list, so you are passing a list to `int`. What do you expect to read from `fname` that can be converted to an `int`? Answer that, and you can fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23679268/3460248). You need to better specify what you want to read from the file.
Any way, to convert a list into integers element-wise, you can use numpy's integer format. For example :

```
import numpy as np
l = ["1", "2", "5"]
np.int32(l)
```

But, be sure of what does your input file contain. An empty line will raise an exception.